# Array reduce wont work with length 1 how can i handle in given case?

Tags: javascript, reduce

I do have an situation

```js
let values = [{value: "one"}, {value: "two"}];
let joinedValues = values.reduce(function(p, n) {return `${p.value},
${n.value}`});

let values2 = [{value: "one"}];
let joinedValues2 = values2.reduce(function(p, n) {return `${p.value}, ${n.value}`});

console.log(joinedValues);
console.log(joinedValues2);
```

When array `length > 1` that time it iterates and returns me the joined values, but when `length === 1` it won't iterate at all and return value object directly.
So, how can I get comma separated string from above example array **using reduce only**.

**Note:** *I can't predict initial value that is dynamic*.

Comment: if no start value is supplied, then the only item is returned for arrays with length of one. [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: what result do you expect with three items? your callback and the outer  structure without start value is highly custom-build for two items.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not solving this in the most obvious way? Why are you using `.reduce()`? The obvious way to do this is `values.map(x=>x.value).join(',')`

Comment: Do you really want to get an exception for empty arrays?

Comment: @Bergi AFAIK it does throw an error if you supply an empty array without initial value in `.reduce`

Comment: @slebetman there are so many ways to do it but i wanted to do with reduce and wondering if there any proper way to do this with reduce

Comment: @NinaScholz can't understand can you explain ?

Comment: @KarelG no it is not throwing any error

Comment: your callback works only for two items, you may try it, but if zero or more than two, you get an error, because either the array is empty or the intermediate result does not contain the wanted property and fills with `undefined`.

Comment: @ShubhanuSharma I was talking about doing `[].reduce((a,b)=>a+b)` empty array + no initial value. That will throw an error. Personally, I am not a fan of using `.reduce` without using the second argument (with other words, it should not be "optional")

Comment: @KarelG but i am not passing any empty array.

Comment: @NinaScholz no it won't throw any error it will just return 0th index value.

Comment: @ShubhanuSharma The first comment in this block was for Bergi, see the `@Bergi` in front of it. It was not aimed to you. My apologizes for some confusions.

Comment: @KarelG sorry for confusion. and no issues :)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't pass the 2nd parameter for `reduce`.

The codes should be like this,

```js
let values = [{value: "one"}, {value: "two"}];
let joinedValues = values.reduce(function(p, n) {return `${p}, ${n.value}`}, '');

let values2 = [{value: "one"}];
let joinedValues2 = values2.reduce(function(p, n) {return `${p}, ${n.value}`}, '');

console.log(joinedValues);
console.log(joinedValues2);
```

and the function in reduce receives 2 parameters. 1st one is for previous value, and 2nd one is for current element of array.

Comment: in this case it is returning ", one, two"

Comment: @ShubhanuSharma the dupe vote came after I could answer, but you have to add a ternary operator: `function(p, n) {return (p ? \`${p},${n.value}\` : \`${n.value}\`)}` or do a simple `values.map(o => o.value).join(',')`